# UIAlertController -- Capturing 'controller' strongly in this block

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

`UIAlertController` is crashing with this error message:

> Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<UIAlertController: 0x7fb9107674d0>)

also with a warning is thrown trying to capture the textFields objectAtIndex.

Any ideas ?

> Warning.. Capturing 'controller' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retail cycle.

I also tried to create a `@property (weak)` reference the warning goes away but the app still crashes with this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // self.controller = [UIAlertController alloc];

    UIAlertController* controller = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Add Alergy To List" message:nil preferredStyle:(UIAlertControllerStyleAlert)];
    [controller addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField * nametextField) {
        _nameTextField.text = [controller.textFields objectAtIndex:0].text;
    }];
    UIAlertAction *save = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Save Data" style:(UIAlertActionStyleDefault) handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        [self save:nil];
    }];
    UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel Action" style:(UIAlertActionStyleCancel) handler:nil];
    [controller addAction:save];
    [controller addAction:cancel];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: what is that line `_nameTextField.text = [controller.textFields objectAtIndex:0].text;` actually here in your view?

Answer (score 2):

```
__weak __typeof(UIAlertController) weakController = controller;
__weak __typeof(UITextField) weakTextField = _nameTextField;

[controller addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *nametextField){

    // nameTextField is the textField being returned in the block
    // if you want to use _nameTextField you need to make that weak too

    nameTextField.text = [weakController.textFields objectAtIndex:0].text;

    // or

    weakTextField.text = [weakController.textFields objectAtIndex:0].text;

}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add
 `__weak __typeof(UIAlertController) weakController = controller;`
 before your `addTextFieldWithConfigurationhandler:`.

Then you should replace

```
_nameTextField.text = [controller.textFields objectAtIndex:0].text;
```

with

```
nameTextField.text = [weakController.textFields objectAtIndex:0].text;
```

Without the _.
_ is for internal access of properties. Here you have to update the field given in parameter

The fact is that you are in a block and if you want to get text from controller fields, you have to make a weak reference to it. The weak controller will prevent increase retain count.

Comment: Hi Guys , thanks much for the help, all errors went away the app did not crash , however !! confused why the nameTextField keeps showing null.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load alertcontroller before the viewcontroller is allocated this warning is because you are adding UIAlertController directly inside **viewWillAppear**

> This method is called before the view controller's view is about to be added to a view hierarchy

1. Just give some time for view to get added to the view hierarchy.to do that use **dispatch_after** or some other delay functionality.
2. Since you are getting textfield input inside a block you can't use **strong** declaration,So you have to declare **__weak typeof(UIAlertController) *weakcontroller = controller;** before entering the block.Check apple developer site [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW16) for more understanding.

Overall modified code is given bekow:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
       dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       UIAlertController* controller = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Add Alergy To List" message:nil preferredStyle:(UIAlertControllerStyleAlert)];
       __weak typeof(UIAlertController) *weakcontroller = controller;
       [controller addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField * nametextField) {
        nametextField.text = [weakcontroller.textFields objectAtIndex:0].text;
       }];
       UIAlertAction *save = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Save Data" style:(UIAlertActionStyleDefault) handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        [self save:nil];
        }];
       UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel Action" style:(UIAlertActionStyleCancel) handler:nil];
       [controller addAction:save];
       [controller addAction:cancel];
       [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
   });
}
```

It will work without any issues.